# [apex]: Database.rollback(sp) not rolling back in my trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, rollback, savepoint

I am playing around with `Database.setSavePoint()` in a trigger. I put it at the top of my `BeforeUpdate` method and then I roll back at the end of the method.

Then I try to modify an Opportunity record in Salesforce through the UI and save. The record gets saved correctly when I thought it shouldn't?

I have never used savepoints in a trigger before so I wonder if there's something that I am missing?

Here's a code snippet.

Trigger:

```
trigger OpportunityMainTrigger on Opportunity(before insert,before update, before delete,after insert ,after update,after delete) {
    TriggerDispatcher.Run(new OpportunityTriggerHandler());
}
```

Trigger Dispatcher:

```
public class TriggerDispatcher{
    /*
        Call this method from your trigger, passing in an instance of a trigger handler which implements ITriggerHandler.
        This method will fire the appropriate methods on the handler depending on the trigger context.
    */
    public static void Run(ITriggerHandler handler){
        // Check to see if the trigger has been disabled. If it has, return
        //if (handler.IsDisabled())
           // return;

        // Detect the current trigger context and fire the relevant methods on the trigger handler:

        // Before trigger logic
        if (Trigger.IsBefore ){
            if (Trigger.IsInsert)
                handler.BeforeInsert(trigger.new);

            if (Trigger.IsUpdate)
                handler.BeforeUpdate(trigger.newMap, trigger.oldMap);

            if (Trigger.IsDelete)
                handler.BeforeDelete(trigger.oldMap);
        }

        // After trigger logic
        if (Trigger.IsAfter){
            if (Trigger.IsInsert)
                handler.AfterInsert(Trigger.newMap);

            if (Trigger.IsUpdate)
                handler.AfterUpdate(trigger.newMap, trigger.oldMap);

            if (trigger.IsDelete)
                handler.AfterDelete(trigger.oldMap);

            if (trigger.isUndelete)
                handler.AfterUndelete(trigger.oldMap);
        }
    }
}
```

TriggerHanlder:

```
public class OpportunityTriggerHandler implements ITriggerHandler{
    public void BeforeUpdate(Map<Id, SObject> newItems, Map<Id, SObject> oldItems){
        Savepoint saveP = Database.setSavePoint();
        try {
            // some code
            Database.rollback(saveP);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
           // some code
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The savepoint specifies the point to *roll back to*. All DML that occurs between setting the savepoint and performing the rollback is included in the rollback.

If you did an `update someAccount;` inside your `try` block, you'd see the effect of that DML operation be rolled back.

But that doesn't include the trigger event that started the whole process. The DML `update` that initiated the trigger's firing took place prior to the savepoint. If you want to roll it back, you'd have to fail the transaction by doing `addError()` or throwing an unhandled exception. Here, you're actually *catching* exceptions, which will prevent a rollback of the entire transaction from occurring based on errors that take place inside the `try` block (other than uncatchable exceptions, like `LimitException` and `UnexpectedException`).

The reference documentation here is [Transaction Control](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_transaction_control.htm#!).

> Apex gives you the ability to generate a savepoint, that is, a *point in the request that specifies the state of the database at that time*. Any DML statement that occurs after the savepoint can be discarded, and the database can be restored *to the same condition it was in at the time you generated the savepoint*.

(Emphasis mine).

Comment: Love your explanation, this makes complete sense now!